# yolov7: cannot import amp from torch.cuda

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, yolo, yolov7

I'm running yolov7 to train on my custom data.

To train I have done following things:

1. Install nvidia cuda 9.0
2. Install cudnn 9.0 in "\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0"  directory.
3. Installed `pytorch` and `torchvision` for compatible cuda9.0 by [following this link](https://varhowto.com/install-pytorch-cuda-9-0/)

Above link strictly says that it requires `torch` version to be less than `1.1.0` for `cuda 9.0`

Versions:

```
python 3.7.1

torch==1.1.0
torchvision==0.3.0
```

Full Error:

```
(venv37) PS D:\aiml_python_code\yolov7-main> python .\train.py --batch-size 8 --epochs 100 --img 640 640 --data .\data\c
ar_dataset.yaml --hyp .\data\hyp.scratch.custom.yaml --cfg .\cfg\training\yolov7_custom.yaml --name yolov7-custom --weig
hts yolov7.pt --device 0 --workers 1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\train.py", line 19, in <module>
    from torch.cuda import amp
ImportError: cannot import name 'amp' from 'torch.cuda' (D:\aiml_python_code\yolov7-main\venv37\lib\site-packages\torch\
cuda\__init__.py)
```

And I'm getting `torch.cuda.is_available()` as `True`

My guess is that `torch 1.1.0` does not have `amp` and above versions of torch do. So how can i resolve this issue with having "latest version incompatibility" in mind

Answer (score 0):

`amp` is introduced to `pytorch` after `V1.6`

you can update your pytorch from the [official website](https://pytorch.org/)